# UIScrollView not respecting minimumZoomScale after changing the subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I'm hitting a problem getting a UIScrollView to update correctly in response to a change in the minimum zoom scale.

The scrollview has a UIImageView as a subview, and the image property of the UIImageView is set in response to the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method of UIPickerView:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *takenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [self.imageView setImage:takenImage];
    [self.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x, self.imageView.frame.origin.y, takenImage.size.width, takenImage.size.height)];

    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(takenImage.size.width, takenImage.size.height)];

    [self.scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:[self.scrollView frame].size.width / takenImage.size.width];
    [self.scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:[self.scrollView minimumZoomScale] animated:YES];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];        

}
```

This works correctly the first time an image is added using this method.  However, if this method is triggered again - even to add the same image as the first time - the subsequent image is displayed at full size in the scrollView, and can't be zoomed out - only zoomed in.

I've dumped the `contentSize`, `zoomScale`, `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale` of the scrollView to the log, and they are the same each time.  The `minimumZoomScale` is being calculated correctly each time.

It's as if the scrollView is being redrawn with a `minimumZoomScale` of 1.0, ignoring the fact it's been explicitly set.  Is there something obvious that I'm missing here?

Comment: Updated: I've worked around the problem by nuking the scrollView if the image picking is cancelled - removing it from the superView, then setting to nil.  The didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method then recreates it.  It works, but it does seem like a heavy-handed way of solving the problem...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem seems to be - not sure if this behavior is documented somewhere - resetting the content size while the current zoom scale is set to something other than 1.0.

The fix is simple: Reset the `zoomScale` property to 1.0 *before* setting the new content size:

```
// See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586577
// first reset before new content size
scroller.zoomScale = 1.0f;
// set new content size
scroller.contentSize = newImage.size;
// ... adjust minimum/maximum zoom scales if needed
```

Comment: Thanks you saved me from pulling *all* my hair out :) Much appreciated and much respect!